# Blender beginner looking for a new workstation

Tags: hardware, workspaces

I'm a beginner in Blender and looking to buy a new workstation. I currently work on a Mac m1 pro 13". I reached out to a local shop and asked for a quotation for an assembled computer. These are the minimum requirements I requested:

- **Intel Core i7 processor**
- **At least 32GB of RAM**
- **NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti**

The shop responded with the following setup:

- **COOLER MASTER FOR-251-KKN3 / 750W COOLER MASTER BRONZE Power Supply**
- **ASUS PRIME B760M-K DDR5 LAN2,5Gb motherboard**
- **HDMI2.1 / CPU i7-13700KF 3.40GHz / ASUS RTX 3060 Ti V2 graphics card with 8GB GDDR6 VRAM**
- **32GB PC5200 Kingston DDR5 RAM**
- **1TB M.2 NVME SSD with 3500MB/s read speed**
- **Windows 11 Pro 64-bit operating system**

Alternatively, there's an option to purchase this computer from Dell: https://www.dell.com/it-it/shop/desktop-e-workstation/xps-desktop/spd/xps-8950-desktop/bdx89530

The price difference between the two choices is negligible, so it doesn't matter.

I'm looking for some recommendations. What would you recommend?

Comment: Your question is off-topic here and I'm voting to close it. See "What not to ask" here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: Hello and welcome, the site is for Blender questions only and hardware recommendations are considered off topic. Try with blenderartists or Blender on reddit